# How do I store decimals with USER-specified precision in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, floating-point-precision

I have an application in which users are typing measured amounts. I would like to respect the precision they are entering when storing the values in MySQL, i.e. if they type 0.050 I don't want that to become 0.05 since that is loosing information on how exact the measurement was done. Is there a way other than storing the value as a string?

Comment: I think the only way other than a string would be to store the precision in another column.

Comment: Maybe INT type would cause a 0 to be dropped, but I wouldn't imagine VARCHAR or TEXT would.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with storing the actual entered value as both a number and a string (though you might look into `DECIMAL` data type for the first part rather than floats).

Answer (score 0):

0.050 is equal to 0.05 . If you want 3 digits after comma, you have to implement this feature in application.

Answer (score 0):

Add always a "control" digit, lets say "1", save to database, then get data from database and always trim ONE time the "control" digit "1" from what you've got.

example:

user inputs 0,000050

save as 0,0000501

get the 0,0000501

trim the last "1" (only the last one be carefull)

k.i.s.s. people :D

edit: proper solution of course, add a column to store precision and right-pad zeroes if needed

Comment: @vatev explain why please.

Comment: Because now your DB data is incorrect and must be massaged back to proper values before operating on it. This will result in headaches when you need to aggregate that data (`MIN`, `SUM`, etc). And when some other application needs to access that data, they have to reimplement this hack as well.

Comment: @DCoder you got to pick a headache in every situation. current headache is converting this to string -that means forget the `MIN`,`SUM` and everything and all the rest you ve said- so i m just giving a choice, its up to the op to decide what suits his needs

Comment: For any operation on that column you need to cast it to a string, trim and cast back to a number. You might as well use a string for storage. (and also what DCoder said)

Comment: @Vatev ok, it may be usefull if he HAS to keep it as float in his db and CANNOT add more columns.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge for handling precision point we are using FLOAT, DOUBLE or DECIMAL data types. In your case if you are not using any function like `SUM(),AVG()`,etc then you can use `VARCHAR`.